# Calculate area for different land cover classes in a raster in R

Tags: r, spatial, raster, area, geo

How can I get the the total area of my land cover classes 1,2,3,4,5 given the following example:

```
library("raster")
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r<-setValues(r,c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)))
```

One approach might be to subset the raster based on these values, however somethig like `a <- area(r[getValues(r)==1])` did not work neither did `a <- area(r[r==1])`.

There is a solution provided on this [website](http://caucasus-spiders.info/r-spatial/raster-basics-3/), however it requires creating new raster layers for each value to be analyzed. I would prefer rather not to do so since my original raster contains lots of different values and is very large. A similar approach is presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425530/calculate-selected-area-from-stacked-raster-object?rq=1), however it works only for small regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the base function `aggregate` on the areas grouped by the values in r and sum them up.

```
aggregate(getValues(area(r, weights=FALSE)), by=list(getValues(r)), sum)
  Group.1         x
1       1  48166136
2       2 126933351
3       3 320336528
```

Comment: Does this method take into account the differences in latitudinal resolution if large areas are mapped?

Comment: I believe so.  Your example code has somewhat odd coordinates as lat-lons, but it did produce different areas for different grid boxes.

Comment: yes it did. I edited my example code slightly to be more comprehensive for that purpose. Would be helpfull if you change the results in your response. thx.